# awk - counting content of files

Tags: shell, awk

I want to make an awk script which counts how many files it has as arguments,
if I use a counter at BEGIN or END the result will always be 1;
Does awk merge the files which I give as parameters ?

The following script prints "1" no matter how many files I give as arguments
("n" will be used to count how many words are in all the files )

```
BEGIN {nrFiles++}
{ n+=NF}
END {print nrFiles}
```

And the final result:

```
{ n+=NF}
END {print "Number of files=",ARGC-1, "\nNumber of words=",n,"\nMean number of words=",n/(ARGC-1)   }
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: does it have to work even if the files are empty?

Comment: it's not specified
but I  found the ARGC variable (stores the number of command line arguments) and if I pass 3 files ARGC=4. I think i can use this right?

Comment: Other parameters like -v will be included in the ARGC count as well.

Comment: @VaughnCato, I don't think so: try this `awk -v a=b -v c=d 'BEGIN {for (i=0; i<=ARGC; i++) printf("%d\t%s\n",i,ARGV[i])}' file*`

Comment: GNU awk also has [`BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` blocks](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE) if you need to use those.

Comment: @glennjackman So is my option correct or not?
(i tried to use BEGINFILE but i guess i don't have GNU awk installed)

Comment: @glennjackman: you're right, it only applies to options specified after the script, which would probably be rare.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print ARGC - 1 }' file1 file2 file3
3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU awk, there's also:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE {n++; nextfile} END {print n}' *
```